# im trying to only show the description of the button i press

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

when i click on the description button, all the mapped containers are showing their descriptions, but i only want the one thats pressed to show its description. so how can i make it so that the container that is pressed will show its id's description?

```
   `import { useState } from "react";

export default function ServiciosCard({ profile }) {
  const [normal, setNormal] = useState(true);
  const [showDescripcion, setShowDescripcion] = useState(false);

  const showDescripcionChangeHandler = () => {
    setShowDescripcion(true);
    setNormal(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div
        className=" space-y-4 mt-3 md:mt-0 h-[450px] md:h-[550px] overflow-y-auto
     md:scrollbar scrollbar-track-[#d0e7d5] scrollbar-thumb-[#ef8eb2]
  text-center "
      >
        {profile.servicios.map((servicio) => (
          <>
            {normal && (
              <div
                key={servicio._id}
                className="bg-[#f7ede2] rounded-md w-[300px] h-[75px] "
              >
                <div>{servicio.unServicio}</div>
                <div>1 Hr {servicio.costo}</div>
                <div className=" space-x-4">
                  <button className="text-[#f77f00] hover:headerButton">
                    Reserva ahora
                  </button>
                  <button
                    onClick={showDescripcionChangeHandler(servicio._id)}
                    className="text-[#f77f00] hover:headerButton"
                  >
                    Descripcion
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            )}
            {showDescripcion && (
              <div
                key={servicio._id}
                className="bg-[#f7ede2] rounded-md w-[300px] h-[75px] "
              >
                {servicio.description}
              </div>
            )}
          </>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

showDescription will show description for all item

you can create a new component Like below an pass srvicio to it.

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function ServiciosCard({ profile }) {
  

  return (
    <>
      <div
        className=" space-y-4 mt-3 md:mt-0 h-[450px] md:h-[550px] overflow-y-auto
     md:scrollbar scrollbar-track-[#d0e7d5] scrollbar-thumb-[#ef8eb2]
  text-center "
      >
        {profile.servicios.map((servicio) => (
          <ServicIo servicio={servicio} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}


function ServicIo({servicio}){
  const [normal, setNormal] = useState(true);
  const [showDescripcion, setShowDescripcion] = useState(false);

  const showDescripcionChangeHandler = () => {
    setShowDescripcion(true);
    setNormal(false);
  };
  return (<>
    {normal && (
      <div
        key={servicio._id}
        className="bg-[#f7ede2] rounded-md w-[300px] h-[75px] "
      >
        <div>{servicio.unServicio}</div>
        <div>1 Hr {servicio.costo}</div>
        <div className=" space-x-4">
          <button className="text-[#f77f00] hover:headerButton">
            Reserva ahora
          </button>
          <button
            onClick={showDescripcionChangeHandler(servicio._id)}
            className="text-[#f77f00] hover:headerButton"
          >
            Descripcion
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    )}
    {showDescripcion && (
      <div
        key={servicio._id}
        className="bg-[#f7ede2] rounded-md w-[300px] h-[75px] "
      >
        {servicio.description}
      </div>
    )}
  </>)
}
```

in this code showDescription do each item that selected by user.

Comment: Thank you!!!! that flew over my head. Ive spent so much time designing this website that my basic react skills have needed a refresher! Thanks again!!